# Wrong Content type Error when Posting to Parse.com RestAPI

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-async-http

Good day, been struggling a bit with this and not sure what to do anymore. I am using the android Asynchronus Http Library [here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to send a POST to parse but i keep getting this error message.

```
 {"code":107,"error":"This endpoint only supports Content-Type: application/json requests, not application/x-www-form-urlencoded."}
```

here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
           client = new AsyncHttpClient();


        client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        client.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
        client.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", context.getResources().getString(R.string.rest_api_key));


    RequestParams params = null;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

           try {
                    json.put(NAME, player_text.getText().toString());
                    json.put(CLUB, club_text.getText().toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

   params = new RequestParams("json",json); //takes a key value pair

   client.post(context, url, params, responsehandler); // posting to https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ABCDER/
```

i have set the header content-type to application/json  so i don't know why i am getting the error. i have also requested the getContentType from the params to see and it gives me the error PARSE was complaining about. What could i be doing wrong? Any help is highly Appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON needs to be posted as the data/body, not encoded in the URL parameters.

Here's another answer that shows how: [POSTing JSON/XML using android-async-http (loopj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052036/posting-json-xml-using-android-async-http-loopj/13901661#13901661)

So for you:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try {
    json.put(NAME, player_text.getText().toString());
    json.put(CLUB, club_text.getText().toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

StringEntity body = new StringEntity(json.toString());

client.post(context, url, body, "application/json", responsehandler);
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry i was away and couldn't respond earlier.