# android POST request Using AsyncHttpClient status code 500 Error

Tags: android

I have a flight book model class. After receiving all required information I want to send all information to the server using POST method. But I always get Status code 500 error. My GET method is working fine. My code is given below.

**This method convert model class as JSON and send POST request to WSManager class**

```
private void sendToServer(FlightBook flightBook) 
{
    try
    {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FlightBookActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Sending Booking request to server ...", true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(flightBook));
        wsManager.post(urlManager.getFlightBookURL(), urlManager.getUserName(), urlManager.getPassword(),null, entity);

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**This is my WSManager class**

```
public class WSManager 
{
    private WSResponseListener wsResponseListener;
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "WSManager";

    public void post(final String url, String user, String password, String requester,StringEntity entity) 
    {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.addHeader(IConstant.WS_USERNAME, user);
        client.addHeader(IConstant.WS_PASSWORD, password);
        client.addHeader(IConstant.REQUESTER, requester);
        client.setTimeout(600000);


        client.post(context, url, entity, IConstant.WS_POST_JSON_CONTENT_TYPE, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) 
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "Post Called Successfully");
                wsResponseListener.success(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) 
            {
                wsResponseListener.failure(statusCode, error, content);
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

onFailure method called always with status code 500

Please help me out. Thank in advance.

Comment: 500 is an internal **server** error. You have to look at your Server log files to find out where the error is.

Comment: Try this approach may be it will help you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13901661/2183890)