# How to create context when sending json content?

Tags: android, rest, post, android-async-http, loopj

Reading this question : [POSTing JSON/XML using android-async-http (loopj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052036/posting-json-xml-using-android-async-http-loopj) in order to post json where is the context value set ?

The accepted answer uses a context value as a parameter within post method invocation :

```
JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
jsonParams.put("notes", "Test api support");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
client.post(context, restApiUrl, entity, "application/json",
    responseHandler);
```

Where is the context set ? Previously I used `RequestParams` for sending data where context is not required but a context value is required when sending json data ?

Comment: I believe this should be a comment to the original answer and not another SO question.

Comment: I disagree Micer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this question should be deleted but can request the context from the main activity using : `Context context = this.getApplicationContext();`